# event handlers - escape/leave and skip the event chain

Tags: jquery

If you have several event handlers after each other.. How can you then leave/stop the chain?

```
$('input').keydown(function(e){
    console.log('first keydown');
});
$('input').keydown(function(e){
    console.log('second keydown');
    // leave/escape the event chain and skip the third keydown
});
$('input').keydown(function(e){
    console.log('third keydown');
});
```

Comment: Why do you have to bind multiple keydown ? Can you just put all this code in one keydown and add some if statement ?

Comment: because they are added from different scopes/objects

Comment: All three of those event handler functions would be triggered on *every* keydown - your logging doesn't make sense. What do you mean *'leave stop the chain'*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stopImmediatePropagation should do the trick: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/

```
$('input').keydown(function(e){
    console.log('first keydown');
});
$('input').keydown(function(e){
    console.log('second keydown');
    // leave/escape the event chain and skip the third keydown
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
$('input').keydown(function(e){
    //will not be logged
    console.log('third keydown');
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8a5zt6qu/1/